# XSL only show 10 loops in the for-each

Tags: xslt

My XML has 100 AgentSales nodes I only want to show the first 10 so far I have

```
<xsl:for-each select="NewDataSet/AgentSales">
    <tr>
        <xsl:if test="(position() mod 2 = 1)">
            <xsl:attribute name="bgcolor">#cccccc</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <td>
            <span style="font:20px arial; font-weight:bold;">
                <xsl:value-of select="AgentName"/>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span style="font:20px arial; font-weight:bold;">
                <xsl:value-of select="State"/>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span style="font:20px arial; font-weight:bold;">
                <xsl:value-of select="time"/>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

New to the site but when I use the code brackets not all of my code shows? at least not in the preview below.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two solutions showing how to eliminate any conditional xslt instructions. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:for-each select="NewDataSet/AgentSales[not(position() >10)]">
  <!-- Process each node from the node-list -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

**Even better**:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="NewDataSet/AgentSales[not(position() >10)]"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="NewDataSet/AgentSales">
    <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= 10">
        ...
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: You can also use it directly in the XPath expression like this: <xsl:for-each select="NewDataSet/AgentSales[position() &lt;= 10]"> Basically the same thing though.

Comment: This would be needed only if there is a sorting performed.

Comment: You can avoid the escaping by swapping: `NewDataSet/AgentSales[10 >= position()]`